# Can emberjs router states handle events that child cannot handle?

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

Like a typical Hierarchical state machine, 
I want to get events that a child state cannot handle but a parent state can, to be handled in parent state. 
I get the error "could not respond to event xyz in state Y"

```
    App.Router = Ember.Router.extend 
      location: "hash"
      enableLogging: true
      x: Ember.Route.extend
        xyz : (router, event) ->
          # Some handling code
        y : Ember.Route.extend()
```

In the above code is there some way of xyz happens in y state, it can be handled by x ?
I assumed that HSM would do that. But its not working

Comment: That is how it should work, I'd check that the routes are nested correctly, if not can you post your actual code.

Comment: its very close to the actual code, I will try to put a jsfiddle, but the case is a mirror of this case.

Comment: also any reference where this hierarchical handling does work ?

Comment: do you have a root route ? Usually the event are bubbled up through states, seems strange it does not work for you... Indeed a fiddle/jsbin wil be appreciated

Comment: @louiscoquio point taken, accepted the right answers.

Comment: Its working now, was my problem of poor indentation. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Yes, the router is a hierarchical state machine and events will be passed the current state and then up to it's parents until it is handled. An error is raised if the event is not handled by any state in the current path.

If this is not working for you, there is an error in your code somewhere.

Comment: Its working now, problem occurred due to bad indentation I suppose.